# Package A depends on package B, but B is in disabled repository

Tags: dependencies, repository, deb, add-apt-repository

I have the following situation: I'm creating a package A, which depends on B. The thing is that B is in a repository that is not enabled by default on the system (in my case, B is python-virtualenv and you find it in the universe repository of trusty).

How can I handle this case and make sure that, when the user adds my repo, runs `apt-get update`, then `apt-get install A`, my package is successfully installed, together with B?

Comment: Universe is enabled by default.

Comment: A-ha, so I guess I have a different issue to deal with... In any case, I guess the question still stands... What if universe was not enabled?

Comment: If B is in universe and a dependency of A, A can not not be in universe itself. Otherwise you will need to add B in A(?)

Comment: @Rinzwind, Say that A is in "deb http://myrepo.com main trusty" and B is in "deb http://another.repo.com main trusty".

Comment: Wont work. if that is the case you need to stuff package B inside package A.

Comment: Or add package B to your repository.